# Copy a subset of folders while preserving directory tree

Tags: rsync

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I am working with a large amount of folders and files organized in this way.

```
/Qarc/Svendborg FU1/1000/1002/Gait1  
/Qarc/Svendborg FU1/1000/1002/Gait2  
/Qarc/Svendborg FU1/1000/1002/Shot001      
/Qarc/Svendborg FU1/2000/2001/Gait1  
/Qarc/Svendborg FU1/2000/2001/Gait2  
/Qarc/Svendborg FU1/2000/2001/Shot001
```

Basically what I need is to copy all the subfolders Gait1 and Gait2 while preserving at least their parent folder (as this holds information on the patient to whom the files in the gait folder belong too).

Based on a previous answer to a similar issue from another user I have tried the following code.

```
rsync -avz --include='Gait*/' --exclude='*.*/'  /Qarc/Svendborg\ \FU1/ /home/steen/recordings/Svendborg\ \FU1/
```

But this code copies all folders and files inside the "Svendborg FU1" folder, and not only the Gait1 and Gait2 subfolders than I am trying to target.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution myself. I am completely sure this is NOT the easiest way to do it, but it worked.
I tried various solutions with regular expressions, but couldn't get them to work. So I ended up adding --include='' and --exclude='' for all the folders that were present in the directory.

```
rsync -avz --include='Gait1/' --include='Gait2/' --exclude='shot_00*'  --exclude='1.*' --exclude='3.*' /Qarc/Svendborg\ \FU1/ /home/steen/recordings/Svendborg\ \FU1/
```